# Is there any idiomatic expression with the meaning "show all the hidden stuff"?

Tags: idioms, phrase-requests

Which idiomatic phrase can be used to express 'showing all the hidden stuff' (it's supposed that nobody should find that out, some scandal things)?

Answer (score 11):

[Blow the lid off](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/blow+the+lid+off) *something*.

Answer (score 11):

[Let the cat out of the bag](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/let+the+cat+out+of+the+bag)

Answer (score 11):

"Spill the beans" or just "Spill it."

Answer (score 7):

*Uncover the skeletons in the closet* or, similarly, *show where the bodies are buried*.

Comment: Coming out of the closet.

Answer (score 2):

From [The Telegraph](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/uknews/crime/8028351/Magistrate-OBE-found-defrauding-charity-after-lover-blew-whistle.html): "A married magistrate was discovered defrauding a charity she worked for after her lover of 10 years blew the whistle." More common is the noun form: [whistleblower](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whistleblower).

Do you want to describe an outsider discovering secrets or an insider revealing them? Most idioms that I can think of lean one way or the other.

Comment: +1 for raising that crucial distinction between discovering and revealing, which I too think applies to most idiomatic forms. *Unearth, ferret/worm out, etc.* as opposed to *blab, squeal, sing, rat, snitch, split, etc., etc.*. As you can probably guess, I also think there are more (mostly negative) ones for the latter!

Answer (score 1):

"Shine a light on" and "Lift the veil" can fit.

Answer (score 0):

The criminal fraternity might say 'peach', 'rat', 'grass' or 'cough'.

Answer (score 0):

If you're letting someone in on the secret goings-on, you can be said to "open the kimono."

Answer (score -1):

how about ***unhide all***