# What is someone who leaks a surprise called?

Tags: phrases, single-word-requests

What is someone whose tendency/act is to leak the surprise called?

Comment: May you rephrase the question? It is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Related: [Word for person who gives out too many extraneous details](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15940/word-for-person-who-gives-out-too-many-extraneous-details) and [Idiomatic expression with the meaning 'show all the hidden stuff'](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3495/is-there-any-idiomatic-expression-with-the-meaning-show-all-the-hidden-stuff).

Comment: surprise leaker?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some more generic terms for someone who talks too much or indiscreetly: ***prattler***, *blabbermouth*, *motormouth*, *bigmouth*.

If it's someone who can't act the part, I would simply say *a bad actor* or, if trying to be humorous, ***a person with limited thespian talents***.

Comment: I would use prattler to describe a gossiper

Comment: Is this answer on the wrong question? This has nothing to do with spoiling a surprise.

Answer (score 12):

If they did it on purpose they could be called a [spoilsport](http://www.wordnik.com/words/spoilsport) or a [party pooper](http://www.wordnik.com/words/party%20pooper) (slang).

Comment: I also like *parade-rainer*.

Comment: Parade-rainer-onner?

Comment: @Kosmonaut, no. They rain. They are rainers.

Comment: @Sam: Parades don't rain...

Comment: @Kosmonaut. A person works on a farm is a farm worker, not a farm worker onner.

Comment: @Sam: I am being somewhat facetious. I actually brought up *parade-rainer-onner* just as a fun reference to the new productive morphological construction we are now starting to see cropping up like [picker-upper](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/picker-upper) and [giver-upper](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/giver-upper). I didn't mean it as an actual correction to your word (just an alternative version).

Comment: Someone downvoted this on 5/6. It would help to know why.

Answer (score 5):

A blabbermouth. While not specifically about them blowing the surprise, I'd also call them a jerk or a party-pooper.

Answer (score 2):

You could label someone **a dampener** and consider it appropriate in this context, although some might argue otherwise.

A known figure of speech goes something like this, from [The Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/dampener):

> Put a damper on something
>
> *Fig.* to have
> a dulling or numbing influence on
> something. The bad news really put a
> damper on everything. The rainy
> weather put a damper on our picnic.

I personally think this could be applied to 'dampening a surprise', and further, the person committing such an act deemed 'a dampener'.

Answer (score 2):

A spoiler? Or maybe somebody who [throws a spanner in the works](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-cobuild/throw%20a%20spanner%20in%20the%20works)?

> If someone throws a spanner in the
>   works, they prevent something
>   happening smoothly in the way that it
>   was planned, by causing a problem or
>   difficulty.

Answer (score 0):

I have commonly heard them referred to simply as a **leaker**, however I do believe that this leans towards informal speech.